# Is it a good idea to use the past perfect in constructions like the one given in the example?

Tags: past-perfect

> It came to me how I **had yelled** at her was wrong. So, I went to her and apologized.
>
> It came to me how I **yelled** at her was wrong. So, I went to her and apologized.

In both the sentences, is it understandable that the yelling took place before the speaker had the epiphany?

In constructions like these, is it a good idea to use the past perfect?

Comment: Both versions are fine, but (particularly because you've not included ***that*** after *it came to me* to help the reader parse it more easily) it's probably better *in this specific context* to use Past Perfect rather than Simple Past. But this is a judgement call that could easily swing the other way if the phrasing were just slightly different. You really need to move on from trying to establish definitive rules for when to use Past Perfect - the bottom line is there are no rules that are any clearer than what you already know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know, you comment or answer the posts I make here quite often. Have noticed how I don't make posts concerning how past perfects as often as I used to? 

The other day, I was reading stuff on how we convey an event that took place recently before some other event took place, in other words, I'm talking about how we use the "Had just" .

Comment: And an some time later I was watching a seinfeld episode was Costanza says stuff about how he had just done something when something else happening.
But, I remember his phrasing, "I just got back from swimming in the pool." 

But, when I'm reading, or watching other stuff, I usually see people using the past perfect how grammar books show how we should use them. @FumbleFingers

Comment: Well, you might suppose it's contextually / semantically obvious that In this specific case the "yelling" must precede the "realisation", but that's not strictly true. If we consider *I realised that how I [**had**] treated her was wrong*, the Past Perfect more strongly implies we're talking about a single act of prior mistreatment. Whereas Simple Past could equally well be used if we're talking about *ongoing* mistreatment (which might continue even after I realised it was wrong). Note that *I realised I was wrong* is idiomatically much more likely than *It came to me [that] I was wrong*.

Comment: Remember how I was telling you about the conversation Julia and I had (had)?

Conversation between the speaker and Julia - Let's say this took place a few months ago. 

And let's say conversation the speaker wants to remind the listener of took place a week ago, where the speaker told certain things about the conversation they had (had) with Julia.

Now, in this case, if we didn't use the past perfect, would that be a problem? @FumbleFingers 

Do we ever actually need to use the past perfect?

Comment: In your *the speaker told certain things about the conversation they had (had) with Julia*, that second ***had*** sounds awkward, isn't necessary, and wouldn't normally be included. In an *actual* conversational context, it's perfectly normal to say *"I saw Julia yesterday and she looked the same as when I saw her last week"* (rather than *when I **had seen** her*). Sometimes you need Past Perfect, but usually not.

Answer (score 0):

The first is grammatically correct and definitely preferable.  The second may be used commonly, but is ambiguous and not preferable.

"It came to me how I yelled at her was wrong. So, I went to her and apologized."

This can also mean that I realized that how I sometimes yelled at her (perhaps habitually, not just how I had yelled at her on a past occasion) was wrong.  To make this clear, maybe she was thinking:

"I yell at her a lot, and it's wrong.  I should apologize."

To complicate this further (we are dealing with English, so it's easy to do), it's possible even to mean "I realized that for years before that day I had yelled at her, and that this had been wrong.", meaning over a stretch of time.  However, it's still preferable to use the first example.

The second one will *feel* correct to many native speakers, but the truth is that many native speakers mangle the Past Perfect as well as Conditionals involving it, so this "feels okay" assessment is as wrong as someone believing that a sentence like "He don't have no friends." is perfectly natural, because they hear people use it all the time.

Also, "that" would help to make the sentence clearer by indicating the subordinate clause, as follows:

It came to me **that** how I had yelled at her was wrong. So, I went to her and apologized.

Just following "me" with "how" can confuse a listener who doesn't know what's coming.  They might be expecting a clause about how it came to the speaker, as in "It came to me how the others had come to me -- by Air Mail.".

[Someone will likely swiftly swoop in to amend my chosen punctuation for a more literarily accepted standard of quotes and commas.]